# Im trying to have the contents of my text element change with the sky element

Tags: aframe

Im doing a simple walkthrough with a text element to act as a description for the images that appear as the sky, I want to be able to change the content of the text when I swap to a different sky. Figuring out how to do the text swap is difficult, can it be don via C# or is there a js function i dont know that would make it very simple to do?

```
<script id="link" type="text/html">
    <a-entity class="link"
      geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1"
      material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}"
      event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
      event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1"
      event-set__click="_target: #image-360; _delay: 300; material.src: ${src}"
      proxy-event="event: click; to: #image-360; as: fade"
      sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"></a-entity>
</script>

<a-scene embedded>
    <a-assets>
        <audio id="click-sound" src="https://cdn.aframe.io/360-image-gallery-boilerplate/audio/click.ogg"></audio>

        <!-- Images. -->
        <img id="goats" src="images/Goat360.jpg">
        <img id="goats-thumb" src="images/goats-thumb.jpg">
        <img id="sheep" src="images/Sheep360.jpg">
        <img id="sheep-thumb" src="images/sheep-thumb.jpg">
        <img id="turkeys" src="images/Turkey360.jpg">
        <img id="turkeys-thumb" src="images/turkeys-thumb.jpg">
        <img id="chickens" src="images/Chicken360.jpg">
        <img id="chickens-thumb" src="images/chickens-thumb.jpg">
        <img id="cows" src="images/Cow360.jpg">
        <img id="cows-thumb" src="images/cows-thumb.jpg">
        <img id="pigs" src="images/Pig360.jpg">
        <img id="pigs-thumb" src="images/pigs-thumb.jpg">
        <img id="geese" src="images/Geese360.jpg">
        <img id="geese-thumb" src="images/geese-thumb.jpg">
    </a-assets>

    <!-- 360-degree image. -->
    <a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="#goats"></a-sky>

    <!-- Link template we will build. -->
    <a-entity id="links" layout="type: line; margin: 1.5" position="-4.5 -1.5 -4">
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#goats" data-thumb="#goats-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#sheep" data-thumb="#sheep-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#turkeys" data-thumb="#turkeys-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#chickens" data-thumb="#chickens-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#cows" data-thumb="#cows-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#pigs" data-thumb="#pigs-thumb"></a-entity>
        <a-entity template="src: #link" data-src="#geese" data-thumb="#geese-thumb"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
    <a-text id="descriptor" value="ABCあいうえお日本語" font="custom-msdf.json" font-image="custom-msdf.png" negate="false" scale="2 2 1" position="-2 2 -4"></a-text>
    <!-- Camera + Cursor. -->
    <a-camera>
        <a-cursor id="cursor"
                  animation__click="property: scale; from: 0.1 0.1 0.1; to: 1 1 1; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 150; startEvents: click"
                  animation__clickreset="property: scale; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; dur: 1; startEvents: animationcomplete__click"
                  animation__fusing="property: scale; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 150; startEvents: fusing"></a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: To change the text you just have to change the HTML attribute in JS. textEl.setAttribute('value', 'new text'); Using mixins instead of templates is probably better: https://aframe.io/docs/1.5.0/core/mixins.html. if you share runnable code it will be easier for people to help and suggest working solutions https://glitch.com/~aframe is great. Best of luck!

Comment: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/alabaster-zigzag-egret Here is working code, would using the alt of the image that the sky refers to work as source text to change the a-text.

Comment: Woud you mind updating the original question with the glitch? Thanks